# Ckeditor Jquery posting data issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I am facing one issue in jquery using `Ckeditor` with MVC.

my code looks like below:

```
<textarea id="typingarea" placeholder="select language before entering question" class="textarea" style="height: 150px"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
   CKEDITOR.replace('typingarea');
</script>
```

i'm trying to post data using jquery on submit button

```
$('#btnSaveQuestion').click(function() {
    var QuestCont = CKEDITOR.instances['typingarea'].getData();
    alert(QuestCont)
    if ($(this).text() != "Update Question") {

        var postData = {

            "QuestionCategoryID": $("#ddlQuestionCategory").val(),
            "QuestionSubCategoryID": $("#ddlQuestionSubCategory").val(),
            "QuestionLanguageID": $("#ddlQuestionLanguageID").val(),
            "QuestionTypeID": $("#ddlQuestionType").val(),
            "QuestionName": $("#txtQuestionName").val(),
            "QuestionTags": $("#tags").val(),
            "QuestionContent": QuestCont

        };
    }
});
```

i'm able to read data from textarea as alert part showing the exact value. But unable to post data with "QuestionContent".post part is working when null value is passed. No other issues in model part.

sample data in ckeditor textarea

```
<p>Hi im here</p>
```

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: @AliSoltani yes

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept and give upvote it to help other programmers for finding a solution when they have same issue. The majority of programmers see accepted or upvoted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the editor content into your main textarea

```js
var QuestCont = CKEDITOR.instances[$('#typingarea')].getData();
$('#typingarea').val(QuestCont);
```

then use the textarea values as normal inputs

```js
var postData = {
                "QuestionCategoryID": $("#ddlQuestionCategory").val(),
                "QuestionSubCategoryID": $("#ddlQuestionSubCategory").val(),
                "QuestionLanguageID": $("#ddlQuestionLanguageID").val(),
                "QuestionTypeID": $("#ddlQuestionType").val(),
                "QuestionName": $("#txtQuestionName").val(),
                "QuestionTags": $("#tags").val(),
                "QuestionContent":$("#typingarea").val() 

            };
```

I would edit the code like below:

```js
$('#btnSaveQuestion').click(function () {  $("#typingarea").val(CKEDITOR.instances[$(this).attr("id")].getData());

        if ($(this).text() != "Update Question") {
            var postData = {
                "QuestionCategoryID": $("#ddlQuestionCategory").val(),
                "QuestionSubCategoryID": $("#ddlQuestionSubCategory").val(),
                "QuestionLanguageID": $("#ddlQuestionLanguageID").val(),
                "QuestionTypeID": $("#ddlQuestionType").val(),
                "QuestionName": $("#txtQuestionName").val(),
                "QuestionTags": $("#tags").val(),
                "QuestionContent":$("#typingarea").val() 

            };
```

```html
 <textarea id="typingarea" placeholder="select language before entering question" class="myckeditor textarea" style="height: 150px"></textarea>
```

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Oh! Sorry.
I have typed false in the complete codes(last section). You need to type "<strong>$('#typingarea')</strong>" instead of "<strong>$(this)</strong>".
I am using this code for the latest version of CKeditor.
Try

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below by [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

**Veiw**

```
<script>
    $('#btnSaveQuestion').click(function () {
        var QuestCont = CKEDITOR.instances['typingarea'].getData();
        var postData = {

            "QuestionCategoryID": $("#ddlQuestionCategory").val(),
            "QuestionSubCategoryID": $("#ddlQuestionSubCategory").val(),
            "QuestionLanguageID": $("#ddlQuestionLanguageID").val(),
            "QuestionTypeID": $("#ddlQuestionType").val(),
            "QuestionName": $("#txtQuestionName").val(),
            "QuestionTags": $("#tags").val(),
            "QuestionContent": QuestCont

        };

        if ($(this).text() != "Update Question") {
            $.ajax({
                url: yourUrl,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                success: function () { alert('Success'); },
                error: function () { alert('Error'); }
            });

        }
    });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult testAction(Question postData) 
{
   // Do somethings
}
```

`Question` is a class that is needed for using it in `Action`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I typed false this section. I edited it.

```js
$('#btnSaveQuestion').click(function () {  $("#typingarea").val(CKEDITOR.instances[
$("#typingarea").attr("id")].getData());

        if ($(this).text() != "Update Question") {
            var postData = {
                "QuestionCategoryID": $("#ddlQuestionCategory").val(),
                "QuestionSubCategoryID": $("#ddlQuestionSubCategory").val(),
                "QuestionLanguageID": $("#ddlQuestionLanguageID").val(),
                "QuestionTypeID": $("#ddlQuestionType").val(),
                "QuestionName": $("#txtQuestionName").val(),
                "QuestionTags": $("#tags").val(),
                "QuestionContent":$("#typingarea").val() 

            };
```

```html
 <textarea id="typingarea" placeholder="select language before entering question" class="myckeditor textarea" style="height: 150px"></textarea>
```

If it didn't work, use the below codes:

```js
$('#btnSaveQuestion').click(function () {  $("#typingarea").val(CKEDITOR.instances[
'typingarea'].getData());

        if ($(this).text() != "Update Question") {
            var postData = {
                "QuestionCategoryID": $("#ddlQuestionCategory").val(),
                "QuestionSubCategoryID": $("#ddlQuestionSubCategory").val(),
                "QuestionLanguageID": $("#ddlQuestionLanguageID").val(),
                "QuestionTypeID": $("#ddlQuestionType").val(),
                "QuestionName": $("#txtQuestionName").val(),
                "QuestionTags": $("#tags").val(),
                "QuestionContent":$("#typingarea").val() 

            };
```

```html
 <textarea id="typingarea" placeholder="select language before entering question" class="myckeditor textarea" style="height: 150px"></textarea>
```